# How to interpret scaladoc?

Tags: scala

How does `foldRight[B](B)` from scaladoc match the actual call `foldRight(0)`

args is an array of integers in string representation

```
val elems = args map Integer.parseInt
elems.foldRight(0) (_ + _)
```

Scaladoc says:

```
scala.Iterable.foldRight[B](B)((A, B) => B) : B
Combines the elements of this list together using the binary function f, from right to left, and starting with the value z. 

@note Will not terminate for infinite-sized collections. 

@return f(a0, f(a1, f(..., f(an, z)...))) if the list is [a0, a1, ..., an].
```

And not so imporant what do the periods after f(an, z) mean?

Comment: `...` is an ellipsis -- it means that a number of closing parentheses have been omitted for clarity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118959/steve-gilham) said, the "..." are just ellipsis, indicating that a variable number of parameters that are not being shown.

Let's go to the Scaladoc, and show this step by step:

```
def foldRight[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) ⇒ B): B
```

That doesn't show enough. What is `A`? That is defined in the `Iterable` class (or whatever other class it is defined for):

```
trait Iterable[+A] extends AnyRef // Scala 2.7
trait Iterable[+A] extends Traversable[A] with GenericTraversableTemplate[A, Iterable[A][A]] with IterableLike[A, Iterable[A]] // scala 2.8
```

Ok, so `A` is the type of the collection. In your example, `A` would stand for `Int`:

```
val elems = args map Integer.parseInt
```

Next, `[B]`. That's a type parameter. Basically, the following two calls are identical in practice, but the first has the type parameter inferred by the compiler:

```
elems.foldRight(0) (_ + _)
elems.foldRight[Int](0) (_ + _)
```

If you used `0L` instead of `0`, then `B` would stand for `Long` instead. If you passed a `""` instead of `0`, then `B` would stand for `String`. You can try these out, they all will work.

So, `B` is `Int` and `z` is `0`.  Note that there are two sets parenthesis  in the declaration. That means the function is *curried*. It receives two sets of parameters, beyond, as well as the type parameter (`[B]`). What that means is that you can ommit the second set of parameter, and that will return a function which takes that second set of parameter, and returns the expected result. For example:

```
val elemsFolder: ((Int, Int) => Int) => Int = elems.foldRight(0)
```

Which you could then call like this:

```
elemsFolder(_ + _)
```

Anyway, the second set receives `op`, which is expected to be of type `(B, A) => B`.  Or, in other words, a function which receives two parameters -- the first being the same type as `z`, and the second being the same type as the type of the collection -- and returns a result of the same type as the first parameter. Since both `A` and `B` are `Int`, it will be a function of `(Int, Int) => Int`. If you passed `""`, then it would be a function of type `(String, Int) => String`.

Finally, the return type of the collection is `B`, which means whatever is the type of `z`, that will be the type returned by `foldRight`.

As for how `foldRight` works, it goes a bit like this:

```
def foldRight[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B = {
  var acc: B = z
  var it = this.reverse.elements // this.reverse.iterator on Scala 2.8
  while (!it.isEmpty) {
    acc = op(acc, it.next)
  }
  return acc
}
```

Which, I hope should be easy enough to understand.

Answer (score 5):

Everything you need to know about `foldLeft` and `foldRight` can be gleaned from the following:

```
scala> List("1", "2", "3").foldRight("0"){(a, b) => "f(" + a + ", " + b + ")"}  
res21: java.lang.String = f(1, f(2, f(3, 0)))

scala> List("1", "2", "3").foldLeft("0"){(a, b) => "f(" + a + ", " + b + ")"} 
res22: java.lang.String = f(f(f(0, 1), 2), 3)
```